# Access Bootstrap Carousel using Angular( not using ng-bootstrap)

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am not able to access .carousel('cycle') using Angular 8. Please inform if anyone has any idea about how to access it. I am trying to avoid ng-bootstrap for my carousel.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal reproduceable example?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.